# Chartingtoolkit ColumnSeries Binding Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I try to Bind this KeyValuePair to a ColumnSeries chart:

```
private KeyValuePair<string, double> _totalProfit;

public KeyValuePair<string, double> TotalProfit
{
    get { return _totalProfit; }
    set
    {
        _totalProfit = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalProfit");
    }
}
```

In my code I fill it with a KeyValuePair:

```
TotalProfit = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Total", 200.00);
```

When I debug this code, everything works fine. Total profit gets the string and double I want it to have, but the ColumnSeries does not display the value of this KeyValuePair. What am I doing wrong.

Here´s the XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="Profit">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart>
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding TotalProfit}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</TabItem>
```

What I want to have is something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the ColumnSeries needs a ObservableCollection with KeyValuePairs to display them. It´s seems to be impossible to display only one KeyValuePair itself.